# crystal report maximum report processing

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

im using asp.net crystal report......i just upload the crystal in server and comiled i got error like"The maximum report processing jobs limit configured by your system administrator has been reached".
then i just used 
protected crysview_Unload()
{
report.close();
report.dispose();
}
then i did'nt got error but when i open this in second time it cant open the crystal report......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try putting the `Close()` and `Dispose()` calls in the `Page_Unload` method, because I think the CRViewer control may still be keeping a reference to the report in the background.

I suggest taking a look at [this forum post](http://forums.asp.net/p/984650/1268025.aspx) on the Microsoft ASP.NET Forums, it seems to be a common problem with Crystal Reports.